# Random Internal server error 500 in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, internal-server-error

My Laravel 4 site was working fine all this time. I made few changes to the controllers, migrations and views and uploaded those files along with the vendor folder. Everything was fine, but when multiple users access simultaneously, the site starts to throw internal server error 500.

I didn't do any major changes but I don't why its happening. The site works fine, only when the traffic increases it throws this error.

**Http Error:**

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

**Filter.php**

```
<?php


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Filters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following filters are used to verify that the user of the current
| session is logged into this application. The "basic" filter easily
| integrates HTTP Basic authentication for quick, simple checking.
|
*/

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    //if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');

    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(false, 401);
        } else {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }

});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Guest Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The "guest" filter is the counterpart of the authentication filters as
| it simply checks that the current user is not logged in. A redirect
| response will be issued if they are, which you may freely change.
|
*/

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CSRF Protection Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The CSRF filter is responsible for protecting your application against
| cross-site request forgery attacks. If this special token in a user
| session does not match the one given in this request, we'll bail.
|
*/

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});

Route::filter('confirm', function(){



    if (is_null(Auth::user()->is_find_match) &&  is_null(Auth::user()->is_match_maker))  {
        return Redirect::to('confirm');
    }
    if (is_null(Auth::user()->email)) {
        return Redirect::to('confirm');
    }
    if (is_null(Auth::user()->dob) || Auth::user()->dob == '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
        return Redirect::to('confirm');
    }
    if (is_null(Auth::user()->religion_id)) {
        return Redirect::to('confirm');
    }
    if (is_null(Auth::user()->caste_id)) {
        return Redirect::to('confirm');
    }



});

/* URLs using confirm filter */


Route::when('matches', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('matches/*', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('profile', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('friendsmatches', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('friendsmatches/*', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('newconnections', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('recommendation/*', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('messages', 'auth|confirm');
Route::when('messages/*', 'auth|confirm');

/* /URLs using confirm filter */





Route::filter('switchAPI',function(){
    $apiKey = Input::get('apiKey');
    if($apiKey != Helper::$apiKey)
        return "";  

});

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(false, 401);
        } else {
            return Redirect::guest('login');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the Laravel log in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: @Bogdan It didn't show any laravel related errors

Comment: @Bogdan It didn't show any laravel related errors...

Comment: Try your HTTP server logs then.

Comment: @Bogdan Ok sure 2 mins..

Comment: @Bogdan It looks like a redirect loop error....

Comment: Then I suggest you check the changes you made to the code that is being run on the route that has the path of the redirect loop URL.

Comment: @Bogdan ok I will check the routes and filters and get back to you

Comment: @Bogdan I doubt the filter.php. I have updated it to the question. the routes looks fine. just added two lines to the old one which is working fine

Comment: @Bogdan are you online. Please help me with this